# Java + FIle Upload + Pulpload

Tags: java, jquery, file-upload

We have a legacy system and user wants to change the file upload page.I looked into pulpload and implemented the UI changes. Now for our java changes we are using an in house framework with web macro and it works like this

```
<form method="post" name="transmitter" action="$url" enctype="multipart/form-data">
..<INPUT TYPE="FILE" name="path_and_filename" id="path_and_filename" size="50">...
</form>
```

Java Code:

```
 MultipartDocument uploadedFile = (MultipartDocument) data.get("path_and_filename");
```

Here this MultipartDocument is part of jar which give us all the info we needed for file uploaded like mimetype, docData, docName etc.

Issue: Pulpload doesn't uses input type= file so how are we suppose to do this, as we can't change the Java code [aslots of other pages are using the same framework].

Comment: Are you using HTML 5 or yet le olde HTML 4?

Comment: By the way, I've checked the generated HTML from [pulpload official example](http://www.plupload.com/examples) and there is this `<input id="html5_18l0re2qj4hh10v8lvp1k401o373" type="file" ...>`, if you look at the page code directly you won't see it but if you check the generated sources then you will.

Comment: HTML 4....and let me the generated sources

Comment: We included the following Js file for the Pulpload plugin and I don't see type = file.
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://www.plupload.com/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"  charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.plupload.com/plupload/js/plupload.full.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.plupload.com/plupload/js/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

Comment: How are you checking the generated HTML code?

Comment: Chrome web developer.

Comment: Again: how are you checking the generated HTML code, which steps are you following to look at it?

Comment: Chrome -- Tool --Developer Tools -- Sources Tab and I have a whole hierarchy structure  to look into...

Comment: Since you're using Chrome, make it easier: being in the desired page, right click in the component you want to check its generated sources, then select *Inspect Element*, then press Ctrl + F and write *type="file"*. There you have it.

Comment: Can you please guide me..my Goal is to ...
1) When user click on Add File button...copy the file in Server Directory and insert the status in a table
2) On click the Start Upload button.....parse the file [csv] and insert into main table..
Do I need to create dynamic input type=file [with attachment]?

Comment: I've accomplished something similar but using [BlueImp jquery file uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and a Servlet.

Comment: If its not too much trouble can you please share...how are you doing it..As I mentioned above my code java code is working correctly....just want to hook up the new plugin.without changing anything on java side....Thanks

Comment: It would be a problem because was in another company I worked two years ago =\

Comment: Done - using BlueImp jquery....Thanks